# Match file path in url regex

Tags: regex, django, django-urls

I need do match path of my image:
`images/05a813eb-df00-4ed6-b8a5-2930f03fbf5d.jpg`
I split it by dir, name and ext

```
def url(self, name):
    prefix, _ = name.split('/')
    file_name, ext = _.split('.')
    return reverse('image_storage',
                   args=[prefix, file_name, ext])
```

so I have `images`, `05a813eb-df00-4ed6-b8a5-2930f03fbf5d`, `jpg`
my url pattern:

```
url(r'^img/(?P<prefix>\w+)/(?P<uuid4>[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12})\.(?P<ext>\w+)
```

but it doesn't matches, help me find solution please.

Comment: You have `images` in the URL and `img` in the regex, why? You have `(?P<prefix>\w+)` defined, but the string you provided only has 1 ``/``. The `[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]{8}` requies 9 chars, but there are 8.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew `/img` it url for storage, `images` it is directory, maybe it will more then one directory later

Comment: Try `^(?P<prefix>\w+)/(?P<uuid4>[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12})\.(?P<ext>\w+)` or even shorter [`^(?P<prefix>\w+)/(?P<uuid4>[0-9a-f]{8}(?:-[0-9a-f]{4}){3}-[0-9a-f]{12})\.(?P<ext>\w+)`](https://regex101.com/r/uN5oI5/1). Ah, I see, there can be an optional dir.

Comment: It might be easier to simplify the uuid part  to `(?P<uuid4>[0-9a-f-]+)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
^images/(?:(?P<prefix>\w+)/)?(?P<uuid4>[0-9a-f]{8}(?:-[0-9a-f]{4}){3}-[0-9a-f]{12})\.(?P<ext>\w+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uN5oI5/3)

The optional dir after `images/` is matched with an optional group `(?:(?P<prefix>\w+)/)?`. The `?` quantifier matches 1 or 0 occurrences. *If* there can be more than 1, use `*` instead of `?` (but I guess you'd have to think of correct "prefix" group boundaries).

Also, `[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]{8}` in your regex requies 9 chars, but there are 8 in fact.

3 consecutive `-[0-9a-f]{4}` can be just shrunk into another non-capturing group `(?:-[0-9a-f]{4}){3}`.

NOTE: It might be a good idea to prepend the pattern with `(?i)` (case insensitive modifier): `(?i)^images/(?:(?P<prefix>\w+)/)?(?P<uuid4>[0-9a-f]{8}(?:-[0-9a-f]{4}){3}-[0-9a-f]{12})\.(?P<ext>\w+)`